# creating a modular function for python3 regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new to regular expression, and I am trying to create a modular function for reading a file in python (on the command line) and using regular expression to remove digits and special characters from the list of string and return as a lower-case string. 
I would appreciate any feedback if there's a way that I can make my code simplier. My goal is to perform extract some basic textual and perform analysis. In this case, I try to analyze the words in a body of text.
Thank you for your help.

## takes a list of string and returns it as a

## lower-case string with digits and special characters removed

```
def normalize(text):
    return_string = ' '.join(text)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[0-9]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[,]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[.]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[;]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[?]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[*]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[-]+', ' ', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[_]+', '', return_string)
    return_string = re.sub(r'[\"]+', '', return_string)

    return return_string.lower()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = read_in_file('sample.txt')
    words = normalize(words)
print(words)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review site

Comment: You can use negated groups instead to list all the characters that shouldn't be replaced. e.g. `[^A]+` will replace find everything except `A`

Comment: [^A]+ seems useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much less verbose. If you only want to accept a-z values, it is much easier to specify what you want with regex using ^ within [].

```
def normalize(text):
    return re.sub('[^a-z]', '', ' '.join(text).lower())
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to determining the characters that you want to keep rather than the the characters that you don't want.  Not a regular expression but pretty simple if you just want a lowered version of the alphabetical characters.

```
def clean_chars(raw_input):
    return ''.join([char.lower() for char in raw_input if char.isalpha()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_data = "This is a testing string abc 1234 &#1)$21"
    print(clean_chars(raw_data))
```